# Submitting two forms in React. One returns string while other returns json

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I'm building one of my first admin areas for a site in React.  I'm using mongoose and MongoDB. When I submit the form to add an artist to the db it does everything correctly and I can see it return the data as a JSON Object.  When I submit a form that adds a piece of artwork to an artist it looks like it works but it actually does not add anything to the database as the data is sent as a string.  I believe the only difference is one route is a POST and one is a Patch.  I can't find any other difference.  How can I make my form send data as a JSON instead of a string.

My Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const artistSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String, required: true },
    last_name: { type: String, required: true },
    artist_painter: { type: Boolean, required: false},
    artist_sculptor: { type: Boolean, required: false},
    artist_other: { type: Boolean, required: false},
    featured_image: { type: String, required: false},
    artwork:[
        {
        type: { type: String, required: false},
        title: { type: String, required: false},
        width: { type: Number, required: false},
        length: { type: Number, required: false},
        depth: { type: Number, required: false},
        image: { type: String, required: false},
        media: { type: String, required: false},
        price: { type: Number, required: false},
        newRelease: { type: Boolean, required: false}
        }   
]
});

const Artist = mongoose.model("Artist", artistSchema);

module.exports = Artist
```

API Routes

```
   // Matches with "/api/artists"
router.route("/")
  .get(artistsController.findAll)
  .post(artistsController.create);

// Matches with "/api/artists/:id"
router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(artistsController.findById)
  .put(artistsController.update)
  .delete(artistsController.remove);

// Matches with "/api/artists/art/:id"
router
  .route("/art/:id")
  .patch(artistsController.addArtById)

module.exports = router;
```

Artist Controller

```
const db = require("../models");

// Defining methods for the ArtistsController
module.exports = {
  findAll: function(req, res) {
    db.Artist
      .find(req.query)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  findById: function(req, res) {
    db.Artist
      .findById(req.params.id)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  create: function(req, res) {
    db.Artist
      .create(req.body)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  update: function(req, res) {
    db.Artist
      .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  remove: function(req, res) {
    db.Artist
      .findById({ _id: req.params.id })
      .then(dbModel => dbModel.remove())
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
  addArtById: function(req, res) {
    db.Artist
    .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, {$push: { artwork: req.body } } )
    .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
    .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },

};
```

Comment: I think you just need a body parser, i hope you already have one, but use the internal from here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html to parse the Form data

Comment: Ok I tried to add it but it still didn't change anything. I may be adding it in the wrong place. The content-type on my addartist request is always json but the content-type on my addArt request is always text/html.  I think that may be the problem.  Not sure how to get that content type to change or know why it's different on the Patch request.